# Linking Memory Script

Tags: python

I am trying to make a linking memory script in python. Script should select a few words *(user determined number)* from several lists. These are my lists and a dictionary for taking user number *(determines how many word will be displayed)*.

```
import random

LIST_THAT_WILL_BE_DISPLAYED = []

Number_of_Every_List = {
    "numberObject":0,
    "numberVerb":0,
    "numberName":0,
    "numberTerm":0,
    "numberCountryAndCity":0
}

listObject = ["computer","monitor","apple","banana","car"]
listVerb = ["fill","fly","emphasize","probe","write"]
listTerm = ["Protocol","FTP","SSH","VPN","base64"]
listName = ["John","Amy","Math","Elizabeth","Andrew"]
listCountryAndCity = ["Paris","Czech Republic","USA","Mexico","Netherlands"]
```

Then It should take inputs from user and append all these to the list above.

```
# TAKING INPUTS FROM USER

Number_of_Every_List["numberObject"] = int(input(f"Number of Object (max {len(listObject)}): "))
Number_of_Every_List["numberVerb"] = int(input(f"Number of Verb (max {len(listVerb)}): "))
Number_of_Every_List["numberName"] = int(input(f"Number of Name (max {len(listName)}): "))
Number_of_Every_List["numberTerm"] = int(input(f"Number of Term (max {len(listTerm)}): "))
Number_of_Every_List["numberCountryAndCity"] = int(input(f"Number of Country&City (max {len(listCountryAndCity)}): "))

while Number_of_Every_List["numberObject"] != 0:
    LIST_THAT_WILL_BE_DISPLAYED.append(random.choice(listObject))

    # CHECKING IF THERE IS A DUPLICATE IN "LIST THAT WILL BE DISPLAYED"

    if LIST_THAT_WILL_BE_DISPLAYED.count(LIST_THAT_WILL_BE_DISPLAYED[-1]) > 1:
        LIST_THAT_WILL_BE_DISPLAYED.pop()
    else:
        Number_of_Every_List["numberObject"] -= 1

while Number_of_Every_List["numberVerb"] != 0:
    LIST_THAT_WILL_BE_DISPLAYED.append(random.choice(listVerb))

    if LIST_THAT_WILL_BE_DISPLAYED.count(LIST_THAT_WILL_BE_DISPLAYED[-1]) > 1:
        LIST_THAT_WILL_BE_DISPLAYED.pop()
    else:
        Number_of_Every_List["numberVerb"] -= 1

while Number_of_Every_List["numberName"] != 0:
    LIST_THAT_WILL_BE_DISPLAYED.append(random.choice(listName))

    if LIST_THAT_WILL_BE_DISPLAYED.count(LIST_THAT_WILL_BE_DISPLAYED[-1]) > 1:
        LIST_THAT_WILL_BE_DISPLAYED.pop()
    else:
        Number_of_Every_List["numberName"] -= 1

while Number_of_Every_List["numberTerm"] != 0:
    LIST_THAT_WILL_BE_DISPLAYED.append(random.choice(listTerm))

    if LIST_THAT_WILL_BE_DISPLAYED.count(LIST_THAT_WILL_BE_DISPLAYED[-1]) > 1:
        LIST_THAT_WILL_BE_DISPLAYED.pop()
    else:
        Number_of_Every_List["numberTerm"] -= 1

while Number_of_Every_List["numberCountryAndCity"] != 0:
    LIST_THAT_WILL_BE_DISPLAYED.append(random.choice(listCountryAndCity))

    if LIST_THAT_WILL_BE_DISPLAYED.count(LIST_THAT_WILL_BE_DISPLAYED[-1]) > 1:
        LIST_THAT_WILL_BE_DISPLAYED.pop()
    else:
        Number_of_Every_List["numberCountryAndCity"] -= 1

# SHUFFLING LIST SO SAME TYPE WORDS WON'T BE SHOWN RESPECTIVELY

random.shuffle(LIST_THAT_WILL_BE_DISPLAYED)

print(LIST_THAT_WILL_BE_DISPLAYED)
```

The problem is if I don't give input that bigger than length of lists, it works fine. But if I give 6 for example, script can't go out from while loop.

[image]

[image]

Why it happens ?

Lastly I know it's an easy question but I couldn't find why it happens despite hours of searching in internet.  :/

Comment: You are not showing the loop on which you have a question. Can you please post sufficient code for us to help you ?

Comment: @ApplePie It's in the second code block.

Comment: There is no output of "Test" in that code block.